# how to replace string continue

Tags: java, string

i writing code for decoding gps in java,  gps send me continue string which i can see in my code but when i decoded it only one string decoded and working stop due to my string have to null for next string i try do it but not get success. any one has idea about this situation

```
package communication;

import javax.comm.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import new8.*;

class Serial
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws UnsupportedCommOperationException, IOException, TooManyListenersException
{
int c=1;

String wantedPortName = "COM6";

Enumeration portIdentifiers = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

CommPortIdentifier portId = null;  
while(portIdentifiers.hasMoreElements())
{
    CommPortIdentifier pid = (CommPortIdentifier) portIdentifiers.nextElement();
    if(pid.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL &&
       pid.getName().equals(wantedPortName)) 
    {
        portId = pid;
        break;
    }
}
if(portId == null)
{
    System.err.println("Could not find serial port " + wantedPortName);
    System.exit(1);
}
else
{
    System.out.println("system find gps reciever");
}
SerialPort port = null;
try {
    port = (SerialPort) portId.open(
        "RMC", 
        1);
    System.out.println("all are ok"); 
} catch(PortInUseException e) {
    System.err.println("Port already in use: " + e);
    System.exit(1);
}

port.setSerialPortParams(
    4800,
    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);



BufferedReader is = null;  


try {
  is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(port.getInputStream()));
  System.out.println("data is ok");
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.err.println("Can't open input stream: write-only");
  is = null;
}

String pt=null;
while(true)
{

is.readLine(); 
is.readLine(); 
  String st = is.readLine(); 

System.out.print("("+c+")");
c++;
new8 obj1=new new8();

obj1.decode(st);
  System.out.println(st);
  st=st.replace(st, "");

}

if (is != null) is.close();
/*if (os != null) os.close();*/
if (port != null) port.close();


}
}
```

Comment: could you format your code please?

Comment: Please format your code for readability, and add the complete stack trace. Indicate which line in your code is throwing the exception.

Comment: I think you should rephrase your question, i dont think alot of people will understand.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is to parse the NMEA data from a GPS receiver via COM Port.

I have seen such a code in C (Open  Source Project Navigation System "Navit").

However I remeber that the serial can be broken, therfore, they check 
if there is a "$GP" praeambel contained in the message. And if the checksum provided in the NMEA line is correct.

I would suggest, that you take a look at that Navit code (although it is in C). You are not the first one who decodes a NMEA from COM port.

Comment: i decoded  NMEA0183 protocol successfully. and also display NMEA 0183 string continue on my computer screen . but problem is my next string not decoding in continue format if i put string manually it decoded successfully.

Comment: even when you fixed your bug, the code is far away from working: NMEA sentences appear in different intervalls: RMC each second, GSV e.g each 5 or 10 seconds. you have to check if the message is the right one ($GPRMC)

Answer (score 0):

The code should look like the following to have a correct flow. Does not say anything on the logic.

```
if (is !=  null) {
    //String pt = null;
    while (true) {

        String st = is.readLine();
        if (st == null) {
            break;
        }
        st = is.readLine();
        if (st == null) {
            break;
        }
        st = is.readLine();
        if (st == null) {
            break;
        }

        System.out.print("(" + c + ")");
        c++;
        new8 obj1 = new new8();

        obj1.decode(st);
        System.out.println(st);
        st = st.replace(st, "");

    }
    is.close();
}
```

Comment: sorry,it still not working only one string is decoded and stop working with some error.